# Loss implementation in Improved-GAN

Tags: deep-learning, loss-function

Recently I am reading the paper **Improved Techniques for Training GANs**, the author define the loss as follows:
[image]
Then I check the code of the article, the corresponding code of loss definition is:

```
output_before_softmax_lab = ll.get_output(disc_layers[-1], x_lab, deterministic=False)
output_before_softmax_unl = ll.get_output(disc_layers[-1], x_unl, deterministic=False)
output_before_softmax_gen = ll.get_output(disc_layers[-1], gen_dat, deterministic=False)

l_lab = output_before_softmax_lab[T.arange(args.batch_size),labels]
l_unl = nn.log_sum_exp(output_before_softmax_unl)
l_gen = nn.log_sum_exp(output_before_softmax_gen)
loss_lab = -T.mean(l_lab) + 
T.mean(T.mean(nn.log_sum_exp(output_before_softmax_lab)))
loss_unl = -0.5*T.mean(l_unl) + 0.5*T.mean(T.nnet.softplus(l_unl)) + 0.5*T.mean(T.nnet.softplus(l_gen))
```

I recognize that the `l_lab` is for the classification loss on labeled data,so it should be minimized, and the `l_unl` is the loss with regard to unlabeled data, and the `l_gen` loss on generated images.
My confusion is why the discriminator should minimize the `l_unl` and `l_gen`,which is the code `0.5*T.mean(T.nnet.softplus(l_unl)) + 0.5*T.mean(T.nnet.softplus(l_gen))` tells us.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this fragment of  Improve-gan.
[image]

Loss_unlabel correspond to L_{unsupervised}.

See in the below.
[image]

Then, by the code of the function *nn.softplus* and *nn.logsum_exp*, you will get the code of **loss_unl**

Hope to help you.

Comment: can you explain why the loss_lab should be that in the code? @ zhangqianhui?

Comment: @Schaffer, If don't understand this original code, you can see this code.https://github.com/gitlimlab/SSGAN-Tensorflow. The implements of semi-gan has many methods. Hope to help you.